# dremio list user API

Tags: api, dremio

I'm trying to query dremio using the documented API to get list of users.
Dremio version:

```
Build
20.2.2-202203241726030461-f7eea3e0
Edition
Enterprise Edition
```

API:
https://docs.dremio.com/software/rest-api/user/list-users/
sample query:

```
curl -X GET --location "http://localhost:9047/api/v3/user" \
    -H "Authorization: _dremiohrr395nv31g8k610616tucp91g" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Accept: application/json"
```

I keep getting this error:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Something went wrong. Please check the log file for details, see https://docs.dremio.com/advanced-administration/log-files.html",
    "moreInfo": "HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"
}
```

It seems that this API is not supported at all.

Is there a published API to list all users so that I can get user name, uid, and role memberships?
I'm trying to avoid using SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

v3  list users API is buggy.

user apiv2/user works